# gnu make ignoring .INCLUDE_DIRS?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have the following make file:

```
$ cat foo.mk
.INCLUDE_DIRS += ..
$(info include_dirs is [${.INCLUDE_DIRS}])
include upper.mk
```

In the directory one level above, I have

```
$ cat ../upper.mk
$(info HERE!!)
```

When I run the makefile, I get:

```
$ make -f foo.mk
include_dirs is [/usr/include /usr/local/include /usr/include ..]
foo.mk:3: upper.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target 'upper.mk'.  Stop.
```

Nor does this work even if I specify an absolute path:

```
.INCLUDE_DIRS += /absolute/path/to/include/file
```

Why is `make` not finding `upper.mk`, even though I have added the directory where it can be found (`..`) to the `.INCLUDE_DIRS` variable?

Note that this **does** work:

```
$ make --include-dir=.. -f foo.mk
include_dirs is [.. /usr/include /usr/local/include /usr/include]
HERE!!
```

Version info:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately `.INCLUDE_DIRS` is effectively read-only:  GNU make constructs a value for it based on a default list of search directories and whatever additions you specify via the `-I` or `--include-dir` command-line option, but thereafter GNU make does nothing with the variable.

If you want to add `..` to the list of search directories for included makefiles, the correct way to do it is to invoke make as `make -I ..`